# Stored Procedure With CTE Fails to Create

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I tested this query which was build with the help from another thread and it worked just fine moved it into a stored procedure where I need to feed it a parameter (value of EID). So the only changes I've made to the query which tested perfectly is to add the @param1 parameter at the top and bottom and the create procedure line at the top.

I can't save it because it is choking on the 4 line an the 'n' stating - SQL80001: 'n' is not a recognized option.

Been a long road to get to this point. Could someone help push me over the finish line here please?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateSubIdx]
@param1 varchar(30) 

WITH n AS 
(
SELECT  DID AS DID,
        sub_idx AS current_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY alt_sub_idx) AS new_id
FROM    GETT_Documents 
)
--SELECT * FROM N
UPDATE  GETT_Documents
        SET sub_idx = n.new_id
FROM    GETT_Documents  G
JOIN    n ON N.DID = G.DID
WHERE   EID = 'AC-1.1.i';

---Repeat for the alt sub idx column renumberation
WITH n AS 
(
SELECT  DID AS DID,
        alt_sub_idx AS current_id,  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY sub_idx)*10 AS new_id
  FROM    GETT_Documents 
 )

UPDATE  GETT_Documents
        SET alt_sub_idx = n.new_id
FROM    GETT_Documents  G
JOIN    n ON N.DID = G.DID
WHERE   EID = @param1;
```

Regards,
Ken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a semi-colon (`;`) immediately before the `WITH` keyword to terminate the previous statement.

Common Table Expressions must be preceded with a `;` - more information on this can be read here: [Why should a CTE start with a semi-colon?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/why-should-a-cte-start-with-a-semi-colon)

You also need to use `AS BEGIN ... END` to mark the body of the procedure.  Below are the changes that should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateSubIdx] @param1 varchar(30) 
As Begin

    ;WITH n AS 
    (
    SELECT  DID AS DID,
            sub_idx AS current_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY alt_sub_idx) AS new_id
    FROM    GETT_Documents 
    )
    --SELECT * FROM N
    UPDATE  GETT_Documents
            SET sub_idx = n.new_id
    FROM    GETT_Documents  G
    JOIN    n ON N.DID = G.DID
    WHERE   EID = 'AC-1.1.i';

    ---Repeat for the alt sub idx column renumberation
    ;WITH n AS 
    (
    SELECT  DID AS DID,
            alt_sub_idx AS current_id,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY sub_idx)*10 AS new_id
      FROM    GETT_Documents 
     )

    UPDATE  GETT_Documents
            SET alt_sub_idx = n.new_id
    FROM    GETT_Documents  G
    JOIN    n ON N.DID = G.DID
    WHERE   EID = @param1;
End
```

Comment: I agree that your code works and you got an upvote but I disagree that you should start a cte with a semicolon. The semicolon is a statement terminator, not a statement beginninator. And a BEGIN/END is not required for a procedure. The initial cte certainly does not need a leading semicolon and the second one now has two.

Comment: I disagree with the `BEGIN`/`END` in this case.  Attempting to create a procedure starting with a `CTE` without `BEGIN ... END` will fail with one of two reasons:  No `;` before `WITH` causing the `CTE` name to be unrecognized, or (in the case the `;` is present) an `Incorrect syntax near ';'.` error.  In this particular case, `AS BEGIN ... END` is required.

Comment: That isn't true. You can create a procedure without BEGIN/END and the first line being a cte and no semicolon with no problem at all. Remember a cte requires that the previous line is terminated with a semicolon. Here look at this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35eb7/1

Comment: Adopted the begin and end statements and negated the semicolon. This was my first ever store procedure so the assist was greatly appreciated!

Comment: @SeanLange Ah - the missing keyword was `AS`.  I had included `AS BEGIN` rather than just `BEGIN` in my tests which gave me those results.  You are correct!

Comment: If you put the `;` at the **end** of all statements there is no need to put another `;` in front of the next statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You don't *need* a `;` at the end of *all* statements.  That implies that it's required, which (in the vast majority of cases) it is not.  I do agree with you that it's not that it needs it at the beginning of the statement, but at the end of the previous.  However, with as often as it is to use a `CTE` in an answer online, it becomes easier to just slap a `;` before the `WITH` than it is to constantly explain to terminate the previous SQL statement with a `;` before implementing it.  As syntactically backwards as it may be to say, it's still technically correct.